# How do I plot the inheritance tree of all the classes in an excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to fill an excel sheet with the inheritance tree of a module. I am able to get all the data related to inheritance but I am unable to think as to how do I plot it in the excel sheet? To take a very simple example, suppose that the source code consists of class B inheriting from class A. The output would be the letter A in a spreadsheet cell and the letter B in a cell below and to the right of A.

I have tried getting all the info using `pyclbr` using the following code but I am unable to think as to how do I plot the relation in the excel sheet.

```
import pyclbr
import os
from operator import itemgetter


def show_class(name, class_data):
    print('Class:', name)
    # filename = os.path.basename(class_data.file)
    # print('  File: {0} [{1}]'.format(
    #     filename, class_data.lineno))
    show_super_classes(name, class_data)
    # show_methods(name, class_data)
    print()


def show_methods(class_name, class_data):
    for name, lineno in sorted(class_data.methods.items(),
                               key=itemgetter(1)):
        print('  Method: {0} [{1}]'.format(name, lineno))


def show_super_classes(name, class_data):
    super_class_names = []
    for super_class in class_data.super:
        if super_class == 'object':
            continue
        if isinstance(super_class, str):
            super_class_names.append(super_class)
        else:
            super_class_names.append(super_class.name)
    if super_class_names:
        print('  Super classes:', super_class_names)


example_data = pyclbr.readmodule('sample_class_module')

for name, class_data in sorted(example_data.items(),
                               key=lambda x: x[1].lineno):
    show_class(name, class_data)
```

The `sample_class_module` mentioned in the code is:

```
from another_module import ABC, DEF


class A:
    i = 10

    def f(self):
        return ('Hello from A!')


class B(A):
    i = 11

    def g(self):
        return('Hello from B!')


class C(B):
    pass


class D(A):
    pass


class E(C, D):
    pass


class F(E, ABC):
    pass


class G(F, DEF, E):
    pass


b = B()
print(b.g())
print(b.f())
print(b.i)
a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
d = D()
e = E()
f = F()
g = G()
abc = ABC()
def_ = DEF()
g = G()
```

and the `another_module` mentioned in the above code is:

```
class ABC:
    pass

class DEF(ABC):
    pass
```

I get the following output:

```
(pylint_pyverse) ➜  uml_diagram_generation python3 pyclbr_example.py 
Class: ABC

Class: DEF
  Super classes: ['ABC']

Class: A

Class: B
  Super classes: ['A']

Class: C
  Super classes: ['B']

Class: D
  Super classes: ['A']

Class: E
  Super classes: ['C', 'D']

Class: F
  Super classes: ['E', 'ABC']

Class: G
  Super classes: ['F', 'DEF', 'E']
```

I expect to properly write the UML output in the spreadsheet.